# Asterisk Voicemail time zone

Tags: asterisk, voicemail

I am using asterisk 11.10. i am trying to change the timezone per voice mail but it is saving all voicemails as UTC timezone. i am trying to setup EST timezone. following is my voicemail user.

```
[zonemessages]
eastern = America/New_York|'vm-received' Q 'digits/at' IMp
central = America/Chicago|'vm-received' Q 'digits/at' IMp
central24 = America/Chicago|'vm-received' q 'digits/at' H N 'hours'
military = Zulu|'vm-received' q 'digits/at' H N 'hours' 'phonetic/z_p'
european = Europe/Copenhagen|'vm-received' a d b 'digits/at' HM

[cty]
3288 => 4286,Brian,,,|tz=eastern
```

Answer (score 1):

The pipe character `|` is only used to separate multiple options. Since you only have one, you don't need it.

```
3288 => 4286,Brian,,,tz=eastern
```

Ensure that you are reloading the voicemail module after making changes.

```
asterisk -x "voicemail reload"
```

Voicemail message files will still be saved with the system time zone, but this will ensure that notification emails will have the proper times.

Comment: I did above settings, but system is still saving time in UTC following is my msg0000.txt  
origdate=Wed Dec 23 03:24:31 PM UTC 2015

Comment: system can save time in UTC depend of version. Have you tried LISTEN it using VoiceMailMain?

Comment: when i listen voice mail using VoiceMailMain, it says correct time, but i have web voice mail setup. user can listen their voicemail via web http://ip-address/cgi-bin/vmail.cgi 
vmail.cgi take voice mail info from msgxxxx.txt and shows detail on webpage. as i mentioned above it saves time in UTC so users can see UTC timezone on webpage. but if they listen via VoiceMailMain then system tell them correct time.

Comment: Ok, so change your web page code to read the timezone from voicemail.conf and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: webpage it not mine. webvmail is from asterisk. see following link.

http://jonathanmanning.com/2010/05/14/how-to-install-asterisk-voicemail-gui-centos-vmail-cgi/

Comment: Doesn't matter whose it is, you still have the source code for it. Asterisk is saving the messages correctly. If you want something that isn't Asterisk to read things then you'll need to take that up in a separate question. But I wouldn't advise doing so until you've had a try at it yourself.